# vsts-task-lib getvariable return null

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to access vsts variables in my javascript code.I am using 'vsts-task-lib/task' library and getVariables() is returning null. This is what I have tried.

In package.json

```
"vsts-task-lib": "^2.4.0",
```

in javascript code

```
var tl = require('vsts-task-lib/task');
  clientId = tl.getTaskVariable('My_KEY');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getTaskVariable()` function is used to get a variable value that is set by previous step from the same wrapper task, for example: `tl.setTaskVariable('taskval1', 'val1value')`

So, using `getVariable(name)` function instead.

Comment: That didn't work either. Finally I ended up using process.env['variablename'] and that worked.

Comment: process.env is ok too, but tl.getVariable({name}) should work too. Anyway, you can post an answer and accept it as answer.

Comment: On the other hand, you may list all variables: `var taskVariables = tl.getVariables(); for (var taskVariable of taskVariables) {
    console.log(taskVariable.name);
    console.log(taskVariable.value);
}`

Comment: Currently, the tasklib version 3.1.7 does not load variables when the script is running, and process.env is used to set variables (in my case for local testing purposes). Probably since every input param is treated as a kind of a secret variable, encrypted in a _store variable while initializing / loading task? https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-task-lib/blob/9ba99acd102ba825041bcc8aaed8f6e9a69791ca/node/task.ts#L227